# Getting the service URL from W3CEndpointReference

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm implementing a web service, however the standard defines that I receive W3CEndpointReference as a part of the request. In the xml it looks somewhat like the following:

```
<b:ConsumerReference>
      <add:Address>http://localhost:8088/NotificationConsumer?wsdl</add:Address>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <add:ReferenceParameters/>
      <!--Optional:-->
      <add:Metadata/>
</b:ConsumerReference>
```

The thing is I need to get to the address part, but W3CEndpointReference for some reason does not have a public address field accessor.
The only working solution I got so far, which I hate, is calling .toString() on the W3CEndpointReference and getting the address using a regex.

Is there any other way to get this property out? Some util class or maybe casting the endpoint reference to the BindingProvider or some other related class?

I would appreciate any ideas. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found in Apache CXF implementation:

```
public String getWSAAddress(W3CEndpointReference ref) {
    Element element = DOMUtils.createDocument().createElement("elem");
    ref.writeTo(new DOMResult(element));
    NodeList nl = element.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing", "Address");
    if (nl != null && nl.getLength() > 0) {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(0);
        return DOMUtils.getContent(e).trim();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Maybe not the prettiest, but certainly better than extracting the address with regex.